# How to trace ped's location within different nodes? - AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

Is it possible to modify agent's variable by tracing it's position whether it's inside or outside a certain node?

I have a string variable `position` inside pedestrian which I want to define depending if agent is outside, inside green or red node (ex. `"Green"`, `"Red"` or `"None"`.).

I digged up the following code that works fine where it comes to tracing if agents are inside a given node or not, but I don't know how to use it so it actually modifies a variable inside an agent.

```
nodeGreen.getPeds(),p->node.contains(p.getX(),p.getY())
```

[my simple model with green and red node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck9pz.png)

[new agent - "pedestrian" with string variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq19t.png)

Many thanks for help,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to periodically check within the `Pedestrian` agent and adjust the variable accordingly.

Best set a cyclic event that executes:

```
if (main.nodeGreen.contains(getX(), getY()) {
    position = "Green"
} else if // ... do for the other types
```

Side note: using Strings here is very error-prone and not scalable. Maybe create a function instead in your `Pedestrian` agent type such as `f_getCurrentNode` that returns a `Node` using the (adjusted) code above. Make it return `null` if the ped is in no node. Now, you can dynamically check for each agent where it is.

Comment: This is truly great, many thanks for help. I will try with function instead of String too, thanks for the suggestion and best practices!